# Canon 5D Mark III mirroring

Tags: canon

I have a Canon 5D Mark III with an Andycine external monitor connected. Since i'm alone shooting myself, when I record, I'd like to see the recording indicator on the external monitor BUT WITHOUT loosing the ability to use the built in back monitor in the camera - in case I need to change any settings.

How can I set up mirroring to both builtin monitor & external in a way to see important info like the recording light or an important pop up like "SD CARD is full"?

Does this make sense?

Right now I can have it mirroring but with no info on the external like the red dot recording indicator. I can configure it to display it on the external but then lose the signal to the builtin monitor. How can I set it up to have the built in monitor keep working?